# How can I install the dialog package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

How can I install the dialog package?

I try these commands, but it doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dialog
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package dialog is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog package is in the universe repository. To enable that, use the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Don't forget to run `sudo apt update`, after which you will be able to install dialog.

Comment: Thanks bro ,I couldn't solve this problem for days.

Comment: @DynamicBits I tried that, but same result. and looking at the /etc/apt/sources.list it looks like I have 0 repos